# Assembly - How To Set A Boolean Variable

Tags: assembly, boolean, tasm, dosbox

Can someone tell me how to set a Boolean variable in Assembly TASM? I have been looking on the Internet and I can't find a proper explanation.

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: boolean is a term from a high level language.  true vs false is just a single bit or a bit pattern or a rule (like in C zero (a bunch of zeros, 8, 16, 32 or 64) is a false and non-zero (any one up to all of the 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits depending) is true).

Comment: Thanks for answering dwelch. I still don't really understand how to use a boolean. Could you maybe give me a simplr example and explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: Use [`setcc`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html) to set a byte to 0 or 1 based on a condition.  You're using dosbox, not emu8086, so you can use the many useful 386 instructions.

Answer (score 2):

@dwelch is right, boolean is a high level concept, but assembly let you define constants that you might call TRUE and FALSE, and you can use them in your code. As a programmer you can create your own concept of "boolean".

Next example program defines TRUE and FALSE as constants, search for digits in a string, if digits are found, returns TRUE, otherwise returns FALSE, and, depending on the "boolean" result, it displays one message or another (made with EMU8086), I use 255 and 0 because it's easy with NOT to turn true (255) into false (0) and vice versa :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
  FALSE equ 0
  TRUE  equ 255
  pass  db  'simple pa55word',0
  msj1  db  'Your password is OK$'
  msj2  db  'Your password requires at least one digit$'
  
.code
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

;SEARCH FOR ANY DIGIT IN PASSWORD.
  mov  si, offset pass ;PARAMETER FOR SEARCH_DIGITS.
  call search_digits   ;RETURNS BX = TRUE OR FALSE.

  cmp  bx, TRUE        ;IF BX == TRUE...
  je   good            ;...JUMP TO "GOOD" (ELSE, CONTINUES).

;THE PASSWORD HAS NO DIGITS.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj2
  int  21h  
  jmp  finale

;THE PASSWORD CONTAINS AT LEAST ONE DIGIT.      
good:  
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj1
  int  21h  
  
finale:  
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;------------------------------------------                      
;PROC TO SEARCH FOR ANY DIGIT IN STRING SI.                  
;RETURN : BX = TRUE  : DIGIT FOUND.
;         BX = FALSE : NO DIGIT FOUND.
;MODIFIED REGISTERS : AL, BX, SI.

search_digits proc    
  mov bx, FALSE      ;NO DIGITS FOUND YET.
repeat:
  mov al, [ si ]
  inc si
  cmp al, 0          ;IF CHAR IS ZERO...
  je  done           ;STRING END REACHED.
  cmp al, '0'        ;IF AL < '0'...
  jb  repeat         ;...REPEAT (IT'S NO DIGIT).
  cmp al, '9'        ;IF AL > '9'...
  ja  repeat         ;...REPEAT (IT'S NO DIGIT).
  mov bx, TRUE       ;DIGIT FOUND!!!
done:
  ret
search_digits endp
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out. I understand booleans alot better now.

Comment: Why did you use 255 for True and not 1?

Comment: @learner, because it's easy with `NOT` to turn true (255) into false (0) and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

In the x86-64 and [i386 SysV ABIs](https://01.org/sites/default/files/file_attach/intel386-psabi-1.0.pdf) for example, variables of C's `_Bool` / `bool` type must the low byte of the register they're in set to 0 or 1, not just any non-zero value, so you can safely `AND` them together and stuff like that.  Using [`setcc` based on a condition](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html) is usually an easy way to do that.

A similar convention makes sense when you roll your own ABI, except in cases when you only need to test a return value for zero or non-zero.  Then @dwelch's suggestion applies: don't waste an instruction booleanizing a value if you can just test the result with something that doesn't care where the non-zero bit is.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Comment: I believe shsucdx uses `rol byte [variable], 1` to check boolean variables. Therefore it uses zero to mean false and -1 to mean true. I think this is a code size optimisation vs `cmp` or `test`.

Comment: Hmm no can't find it. Maybe I was recalling another program.

Comment: Found it after all, it's in their `nasm.mac` file. "A flag is a boolean byte variable. It is 0 for off and -1 for on (and *not* anything else)." And they check it using `rol`: "`tflg    [flag]`    ==>   `rol     byte [flag], 1`" and the comments say "tflg: test a flag (set carry if on)."

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what @Peter Cordes said, the [i386 ABI](https://01.org/sites/default/files/file_attach/intel386-psabi-1.0.pdf) and [x86-64 ABI](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI) also say this about Booleans:  "When stored in integer registers (except for passing as arguments), all 4 (x86-64: 8) bytes of the register are significant; any nonzero value is considered true." So make sure to also consider the upper bytes in this case.

Comment: That's weird, the ABI has no business specifying the private internals of a function that aren't relevant across a function boundary.  If you don't want to set all the bytes, only test the low byte later.  That part of the ABI seems more like a misguided attempt to document what GCC chooses to do.